# EJB not deployed on JBoss AS 5.0.x

Tags: jboss, ejb

Im was trying to build an example from book Im reading about JBoss 5 (JBoss AS 5 Developmet), however even the code directly from the book simply does not work.

This is my interface:

```
@Remote
public interface Mailer {

    public void sendMail(String aToEmailAddr, 
                         String aSubject, String aBody);

}
```

This is EJB that implements this interface

```
@Stateless  
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="remote/MailerEJB")

public  class MailerBean implements Mailer {... }
```

And this is the client application which tries to lookup the bean.

```
public class MailClient {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
       {
          InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
          Mailer mailer = (Mailer) ctx.lookup("remote/MailerEJB");


       }

}
```

When i try to run MailClient class ive got following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remote not bound
```

I also have jndi.properties file, which I added to the build path, and it looks like this>

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jnp.interfaces
```

Even in jmx-console I simply cant see remote/MailerEJB Bean.

Im using jboss-5.0.1.GA + JBDS + java 1.7.0

Can somebody help me out ?

Comment: Does setting `java.naming.factory.url.pkgs` to `org.jboss.naming.client` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you've to be sure that the EJB is properly deployed in the JBoss and the binding name it's given, so if you can't see the bean in the JNDIView of the JMX Console, it's surely a deployment problem. To be sure that it's correctly deployed you can check the JBoss logs in the moment of deploying the EJB (you ejb-jar or ear), look for a line similar to:

```
EJBBindingName - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
```

In your case, if the binding you've defined is correct, it should be:

```
remote/MailerEJB - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
```

This line indicates the real JNDI name that is given to the EJB, and it's the one you've to use in your remote calls.

On the other hand, try to remove the line between the annotations and the class definition:

```
@Stateless  
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="remote/MailerEJB")
public  class MailerBean implements Mailer {... }
```

Moreover in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380465/call-ejb-remote/13386464#13386464) you can find specific instructions about how to make a remote call to an EJB from a simple command line Java program.

Comment: Well, im sure that my EJB is not deployed, as I said i havent seen it in jmx-console nor in jboss server log.

Comment: In that case, the problem is not really in the remote access to the EJB, but in the EJB itself. When you deploy the EJB you should see something in the log file, at least error. Could you check the log file for a deployment error?

Comment: Thats the problem, there is absolutely nothing about this EJB in my log. http://pastebin.com/ehGUCbp7 . It just seems that those annotations are completely ignored.

Comment: Yes, in the logs it doesn't show any EJB deployment. How do you deploy the ear/jar, placing it in the deploy directory? And what's its name? By the way, I don't think it's really the cause of your problem, but you're running JBoss with an OpenJDK1.7, remember that JBoss 5.x is officially certified to run on JDK 1.6.

Comment: I think this is the core of the problem - the way of deployment. I followed the tutorial, and Im deploying it via JBDS. When creating a project I left "add project to an ear" and "create an ejb client jar module to hold the client interfaces and classes" unchecked.  Then I simply added project to the server, and deployed it with clicking on it and selecting "full publish" option. Then simply "start" jboss server and the project was deployed. However without EJBs.

Comment: So, are you sure that the ejb-jar is inside the ear file? You can check it just simply extracting the file. On the other hand, to deploy an application in JBoss you just have to move the file in the deploy directory, so check if the JBDS has copied the ear file in the deploy directory for you as well.

Comment: As I said, I left those option unchecked, since I was deploying via my IDE. I cant see any EAR file withing the project directory. Here is my file structure http://pastebin.com/0Mv9ARfN

Comment: Then you've to check it, and make sure you've the ejb-jar inside your ear.

Comment: Working now - just copied *.jar file into the server/default/deploy folder, and its working ! THX !